# Unable to form POJO from json string using Jackson: Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following string:

```
{"networks":[["divakar","64:66:",4,1,-37,-98],["OPTUSA202B26","00:1e:2a:",3,2,-40,-98],["Mantri","00:1e:a6:1",5,6,-41,-98],["belkin.5D7","08:86:3",5,6,-38,-98]]}
```

and I am using the following objects:

```
public static class Network{
        private ArrayList<SoftAPInfo> networks;

        public Network(ArrayList<SoftAPInfo> networks) {
            this.networks = networks;
        }

        public Network(){

        }

        public ArrayList<SoftAPInfo> getNetworks() {
            return networks;
        }

        public void setNetworks(ArrayList<SoftAPInfo> networks) {
            this.networks = networks;
        }
    }


public static class SoftAPInfo {
        private ArrayList<String> list;
        public ArrayList<String> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public void setList(ArrayList<String> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public SoftAPInfo() {

        }
}
```

and the following jackson command:

```
TypeReference<Network> typeRef = new TypeReference<Network>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Object jsonObject =  mapper.readValue(response, typeRef);
            callback.onSuccess(jsonObject);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but i keep getting an exception: 
cannot deserialize object out of start_array token

could someone please help me figure out the issue here?

Thanks, 
Sunny

Comment: please explain the down flag that I could improve upon it. thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is that each "network" isn't a JSON object, it's a JSON array. If you want to deserialize a plain JSON array into a Java object, you'll need to provide a custom deserializer that understands the object order and can create an appropriate POJO.

Comment: thanks. could you please help explain with an example?